# Python KeyError: u'image.composite_image' While saving figure as SVG

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib

The line:

```
destination1 = "test.svg"
destination2 = "test.png"
plt.savefig(destination1, format='svg')
```

worked fine in my python script until I.T. updated my machine to run office 2013 (which should be unrelated). I run python through enthought Canopy.

I updated matplotlib, pillow, amoung a plethora of other unrelated packages through pip, yet I get an exception thrown for that line that reads

```
KeyError: u'image.composite_image'
```

so falling back on a png

```
plt.savefig(destination2, format='png', dpi=700)
```

works fine but I would really like to be able to save as an svg again. a printout of the error is found below im at a complete loss as to how to solve this

[image]